# wordpress responsive theme or twitter bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have been reading Twitter bootstrap for quite a while now. It gives pre-made functionality for so many things using CSS classes, I can create anything. Along with a lot of jQuery plugins already integrated in the package.

On the other hand I see there is a theme with the name `responsive` is available in Wordpress which gives same functionality. I am confused to choose what should I choose for my upcoming-project. I am going to use Wordpress for the project.
I need to know the following.

- Which one is easy to learn? Responsive documentation doesn't seem to be user friendly.
- Is it fine to use `bootstrap` in wordpress theme? Do i have to do much customization than `responsive` if i use `bootstrap`?
- Will using `responsive` give me any benefit over `bootstrap` and in the future how can i reuse responsive theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what responsive theme or types of customization you are referring to.
While I can't speak to the specific theme, I can say a few things about bootstrap.

1. Bootstrap offers lots of flexibility when it comes to a responsive layout as witnessed in the [docs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html). You can use fixed or fluid layouts and nest and offset content.
2. Bootstrap offers a lot of flexibility in aesthetic choices as well. Aside from customizing the css yourself there are free options available including those on [bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/) .
3. If you need an example or theme of bootstrap/wordpress integration you can find one at [BootstrapWP](http://bootstrapwp.rachelbaker.me/).

Even if you don't want the look and feel of the bootstrap components you can still use it for the responsive features. It's not terribly hard to set up and is very reusable. It's also maintained very well and has excellent documentation. It gets my vote.